# Frame ancestor is set to none even though it's not

Tags: nginx, iframe, keycloak, openid, matrix-synapse

I'm running a matrix synapse instance with OpenID Keycloak and as web-client, I use Riot.
I receive has refused to connect with : "Refused to frame 'https://matrix.domain.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".

However I have no problem connecting to it through Riot, I get the error when I display Riot in an iframe and try login, all the websites are of same domain wildcard.

My nginx config on matrix.instance.com is

server {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               server_name matrix.domain.com;                                                                                                                                                                                                             root /var/www/matrix.domain.com;                                                                                   index index.html;                                                                                                        #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';                                                                          add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors https://website1.domain.com https://website2.domain.com>                                                                                                                               location / {                                                                                                                     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;                                                                          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;                                                                             proxy_set_header Host $host;                                                                                            proxy_pass http://localhost:8008;                                                                              }

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, matrix-synapse throws the flag from this directory
/opt/venvs/matrix-synapse/lib/python3.8/site-packages/synapse/http/server.py

The flag is declared within this file. Hence giving you issues when reverse proxying synapse.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).